# M1 Silicon Mac shows i386 as architecture even though /bin/zsh is the shell

Tags: apple-silicon

On my M1 Macbook I have `iTerm` as the terminal I use and when I enter `echo $SHELL` I get `/bin/zsh`. However, `arch` gives `i386`. I had migrated the computer from Intel to Silicon and never got the transition correct.

What should I do at this point to get `arch` as `arm64`? Thanks

Comment: Is iTerm running in Rosetta mode (you can check by selecting the application icon and pressing Cmd-I)? If you run Terminal instead of iTerm, what does `arch` return?

Comment: I do not see the Rosetta mode option in the cmd-i info page. When I run in terminal it returns `arm64`

Comment: Then iTerm itself is an Intel binary (should also be visible in the Get Info screen, in the first line of the General section). Can you update it to the most recent version?

Comment: Ah! That solved it! I updated to the most recent version and `arch` now shows `arm64`. I didn't know it being an Intel binary could make it only work in `i386`, I'm curious why would that be generally? Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, newly launched processes "inherit" the architecture from the process which launches them. So if iTerm is an Intel binary, it and any processes launched (including `zsh`) will be run via Rosetta.

To solve, you need to update iTerm to an ARM or Universal binary.